# Property "BsGridView.ajaxType" is not defined

Tags: yii

I have installed Yii users and rights and now i am adding bootstrap to the "webapp/protected/modules/user/admin/view" files, but i am getting an error:

```
Property "BsGridView.ajaxType" is not defined
```

Comment: Hi @Salik Asad Show the original code and the code with bootstrap please

Comment: well there is no such code for bootstrap, i have just to change few things like CHtml to BsHtml or textFiled to textFieldControlGroup.
and there are 6 php files which needs these types of changes. can you specify which file code should i paste here..??

Answer (score 0):

The "BsGridView.ajaxType" error i think is releated to the fact you haven't include the bootstrap  class for the component you are using. You shold start form code working in boostrap and the gradually add the code for the extensions

Comment: This is the exact error i am getting..!!
C:\wamp\www\emergency_response\protected\extensions\bootstrap\widgets\BsGridView.php(144):
CComponent->__get('ajaxType')